# Fast selection and assignment using Hierarchical indexing (MultiIndex)

Tags: python, pandas

I work with a large dataset in Pandas (over 18000000 rows, 8 columns) and want to assign one of the columns in certain rows to True. I use Hierarchical indexing and have my DataFrame Structured as follows:

```py
                    col1       col2       ...     col8     
name    position                              
"name2"   1        False     -0.827317           0.569605
          2        False     -0.273178           0.997953
          3        False     -0.827317           0.569605
         ...        ...        ...        ...      ...
         15000     False     -0.827317           0.569605
         15001     False     -0.001015           0.569605
"name2"   1        False     -0.827317           0.827317
          2        False     -0.827317           0.569605
          3        False     -0.827317           0.001015
         ...        ...        ...        ...      ...
         15000     False     -0.827317           0.569605
         15001     False     -0.998997           0.569605
"name3"   1        False     -0.827317           0.569605
          2        False     -0.827317           0.000000
          3        False     -0.827317           0.569605
         ...        ...        ...        ...      ...
         15000     False     -0.998997           0.569605
         15001     False     -0.827317           0.998997

...      ...        ...        ...        ...      ...
```

I want to assign certain positions, based on previous calculations in col1 to true. I want to do this for all indexes in my "name" index.

So first I tried to select the correct rows by using this tuple index.

```py
df.loc[(all_names, positions), 'col1'] = True
```

It worked, but it was incredibly slow, which made it unusable in practice. I tried to time it in Jupyter Notebook, but the iPython kernel crashed when i used `%%timeit`.

So then I tried to use this code:

```py
for name in all_names: 
    df.loc[name].loc[positions, 'col1'] = True
```

It was at least a factor ~10 faster, to my surprise. I am aware that using `df.loc[].loc[] = True` is not an appropriate way of solving this due to `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.` but it actually works as I want it to, and all the correct values are set. But it is still slow (about 1 minute for the entire dataset)

I thought that iterating over all names for sure couldn't be the fastest way, so I attempted to use slicers

```py
df.loc[(slice(None), positions), 'col1'] = True
```

but it performed identical to my first attempt.

What is the best and fastest way to select and assign certain values using Hierarchical Indexing? When wanting to use all indexes on the first level and then only some on the second level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As every `name` part of the multiIndex is going to be selected, maybe trying indexing by `get_level_values(1)`, where (1) indicates `position`:

```
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(1).isin(positions), 'col1'] = True
```

Try and see if that offers any speedup.

Comment: This worked incredibly well. It took only 2 seconds, compared to several minutes with my previous attempts. Thank you!

Comment: @cjerik Glad it helped!

Comment: Thought that I should add to this that by using     ```df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values(1).isin(positions), df.columns.get_loc('col1')] = True``` I got an immense improvement in speed, when running on a larger dataset it went from taking hours to just minutes. @Tom